# Cannot access static method in a non-static context

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, static-methods

I created a partial view that uses a method called GetUrl but I got the error `cannot access static method in a non static context`.

Here's how I implemented the method:

```
public class TimeLineStep
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public TimeLineStatus Status { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }

    public static string GetUrl(string code)
    {
        switch (code)
        {
            case "1":
                return "#";
            case "2":
                return "#";
            case "3":
                return "#";
            case "4":
                return "#";
            case "5":
                return "#";
            case "6":
                return "#";
            case "7":
                return "#";
            default:
                return "#";
        }
    }
}
```

and my partial view :

```
@using UI.Controls
@model List<Web.Models.TimeLineStep>
@{
    Layout = null;
}
@using (Html.ContentBlock("Yellow", ""))
{
    <ul>
        @foreach (var menuItem in Model)
        {
            <li>
                <a href="@menuItem.GetUrl(menuItem.Code)"> @menuItem.Title </a>
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
}
```

This partial view generates a vertical menu with URLs. How can I call my static method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You call a static method on the class itself, not an instance of the class.

```
<a href="@TimeLineStep.GetUrl(menuItem.Code)"> @menuItem.Title </a>
```

But are you sure you meant to make that static? It seems like what you wanted was:

```
public string GetUrl()
{
    switch (this.Code)
         ....
```

which would then be called as

```
<a href="@menuItem.GetUrl()"> @menuItem.Title </a>
```

Comment: thank you.I was told to make it static but definitely you re right ,if there s any other method for the call just to let the method static? there is a way to refer to it from the class it's defined in, not an instance of that class?

Comment: @YosrJ - im sorry I dont understand your follow up question?